# How to call NextJs api that fetch data from MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, react-admin

I have created a **products** api that fetch data from MongoDb.

```js
import dbConnect from "../../../lib/mongodb";
import Products from "../../../models/Products";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  dbConnect();
  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const products = await Products.find();
      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }

  if (method === "POST") {
    try {
      const product = await Products.create(req.body);
      res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
}
```

I am successfully connect to database and fetch the data in localhost.But when I deploying it on vercel, I take **500 Internal Error**. I am using this api in **react-admin**  **dataProvider.js** just like that

```js
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";

import { stringify } from "query-string";
const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;

const dataProvider = {
  getList: (resource, params) => {
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const query = {
      range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
    };
    const url = `/api/${resource}?${stringify(
      query
    )}`;  //here the API that I call

    return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
      data: json.map((resource) => ({ ...resource, id: resource._id })),
      total: parseInt(headers.get("content-range").split("/").pop(), 10),
    }));
  },
};

export default dataProvider;
```

Here the screenshots of **network** in developer tools

In Local
[image]
In Production
[image]

I want to share my domain link
https://electronic-products47.vercel.app/

Comment: Can you show us the server error you get in Vercel logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in Monge DB network access You need to add 0.0.0.0/0 IP to the "whitelist" so that Your Vercel server is not being blocked by Mongo DB Database.

[image]